# Find the number of bit strings of length 10,000 that contain 7 consecutive 0's

Tags: probability, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How would I go about finding this without manually computing all the possibilities?

Comment: exactly 7, or at least 7? E.g the all 0 bitstring is included?

Comment: At least 7. So yes, the all 0 bit string would count.

Comment: Let $a_n$ be the the number of bistrings of length $n$ that have at most 6 consecutive $0$'s. There is, I think, a recursion formula for $a_n$, Fibonacci-like. Then you want $2^{10000} - a_{10000}$. Just an idea.

Comment: Let $T_k$ denote the number of bits needed to produce $k$ consecutive zeroes, then $T_0=0$ and $T_{k+1}=T_k+1$ or $T_{k+1}=T_k+1+T'$ with equal probabilty, where $T'$ is distributed like $T_{k+1}$ and independent of $T_k$. In terms of generating functions $g_k(s)=E(s^{T_k})$, this translates as $g_0(s)=1$ and $$g_{k+1}(s)=g_k(s)\tfrac12s(1+g_{k+1}(s)).$$ Thus, $$g_{k+1}(s)=\frac{sg_k(s)}{2-sg_k(s)}.$$ Iterating this yields $$g_k(s)=\frac{s^k(2-s)}{p_k(s)}\qquad p_k(s)=s^{k+1}+2^{k+1}(1-s).$$ The behaviour of $P(T_k=n)$ is ruled by the first root $r_k$ of $p_k$ after $1$ ...

Comment: ... in the sense that $$P(T_k=n+k)\sim\frac{2-r_k}{|p'_k(r_k)|}\frac1{r_k^{n+1}}.$$ 
Summing this yields $$P(T_k\geqslant n+k)\sim\frac{2-r_k}{r_k-1}\frac{1}{|p'_k(r_k)|}\frac1{r_k^{n}}.$$ For $k=7$, $r_7\approx1.00403$ and one gets $$P(T_7\geqslant n+7)\approx\frac{0.997}{r_7^n},$$ for example, $$P(T_7\geqslant 10000)\approx3.5\cdot10^{-18}\approx2^{-57.987}.$$ *Finally*, the total number of strings of length $10000$ is $2^{10000}$ hence the number of such strings with no $7$ successive zeroes is approximately $$2^{10000-57.987}\approx2^{9943}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $a_{n,k}$ be the number of $n$-length strings that do NOT contain 7 consecutive 1's that end in exactly $k$ ones then you have

$$a(n,k) = a(n-1,k-1)$$
$$a(n,0) = \sum_{k=0}^6 a_{n-1,k}$$

which you can reduce into a single variable recursion for $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^6 a_{n,k}$ and then solve using standard recursion relation solution techniques.

Then your answer is $2^n - \sum_{k=0}^6 a_{n,k}$.